# Artifactory - Lots of "org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe" in catalina logs

Tags: artifactory

We're running Artifactory Pro 7.4.3, and there are a great many errors in the catalina logs in /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/tomcat/ like this:

```
30-Apr-2020 12:11:26.218 SEVERE [http-nio-8081-exec-1078] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:91)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:662)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:395)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:385)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:280)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:195)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:97)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:513)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAnonymousIfPossible(AccessFilter.java:474)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:251)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:78)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.java:75)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
                at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryTracingFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryTracingFilter.java:27)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:124)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:304)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:833)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:738)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:399)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:377)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
                at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:563)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:325)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:224)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:300)
                at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2315)
                at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2270)
                at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2291)
                at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2246)
                at org.artifactory.rest.response.JerseyArtifactoryResponse$MustBeConsumed.write(JerseyArtifactoryResponse.java:137)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:79)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:61)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:251)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:109)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:85)
                ... 65 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1306)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:731)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:501)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:439)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:623)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:116)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:225)
                at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:602)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:352)
                ... 87 more
```

To my untrained eye, that's not much to go on in terms of where to look next for debugging purposes.

Has anyone seen anything like this in Artifactory before?

Many thanks,
alec